# PIC18f45J50 2nd Serial port?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, serial, uart, microchip

I am working on a GPS tracker Project where i need to interface with a GPS module and a UMTS module for 3g connectivity. with this i need 2 serial ports on a single microcontroller.

For this requirement i opted for PIC18F45J50, As i saw in it's datasheet that it has 2 EUSART ports.

It has first Rx/Tx pins on pin 1 and 44 respectively... but i can't find the second serial port.

So are there any examples or guidance on the second serial port on the microcontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many 8-bit PIC's has PPS - peripheral pin select. You can choose on which pins some of digital peripherals will be connected (EUSART2 also). Look for PPS description (10.7 in datasheet).

Answer (score 0):

From the [data sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39931d.pdf) (part 20.0):

> The pins of EUSART1 and EUSART2 are multiplexed with the functions of
>   PORTC (RC6/TX1/CK1/RP17 and RC7/RX1/DT1/SDO1/RP18)             and
>   remapped (RPn1/TX2/CK2 and RPn2/RX2/DT2), respectively.

Part 10.7 explains how the peripheral pin select (PPS) works, that is used to map RX2/TX2 to the pin where you need it.

Comment: Can u please provide a link to the example?  thanks for the answer btw.